# Is it possible to add just Xamarin support to existing Visual Studio 2008 installation?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2008

I already have a fully functional Visual Studio 2008 installed on my system, complete with C# and VB .Net.

Now I need to just add Xamarin support to my existing installation. Is there a way to do this, without having to download Visual Studio again?

When I try to download Xamarin, it gives me a "Visual Studio Community 2017 Installer" with so many language components, that it is really difficult to identify the bare minimum I would need to create a Xamarin project.

Appreciate all guidance and clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Xamarin supports Visual Studio 2015 and 2017:

> Xamarin for Visual Studio supports any Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 (Community, Professional, and Enterprise).
>
> To develop Xamarin.Forms apps for the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) requires Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2015 or 2017.

Due to network issues, I create offline installers for Visual Studio 2017 Community, Professional, and Enterprise via the `-layout` cmd-line option. This layout can be later updated as patches and new releases are released.

You can create an offline installer that contains the *minimum* installer setup for Xamarin by downloading either the `vs_enterprise.exe`, `vs_professional.exe`, or `vs_community.exe` from:

(Pick the correct one depending upon your **license key** otherwise you will have to start from scratch and re-download the whole thing.)

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio

Then you can then:

- Change the exe to one that you download
- Change the language to only download the language(s) you want
- Select the component ids, only  `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat` in this case to get just what is required to work with Xamarin (you can always add additional components to Visual Studio later...

> ID: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat
>
> Description: Build cross-platform applications for iOS, Android or Windows using Xamarin.

```
& '.\vs_enterprise.exe' 
--layout C:\vs2017offline 
--lang en-US
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat
--includeRecommended
```

Note: This will produce an `vs2017offline` directory that is about **2GB** in size.

If you already have the Android SDK installed (via Android Studio or another Visual Studio install), you can create a layout that does not contain it. After installation and launching Visual Studio, you will need to assign the location of the Android SDK within the Xamarin setting.

```
& '.\vs_Enterprise15.4(preview).exe' 
--layout C:\vs2017offline15.4Preview 
--lang en-US 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat 
--add Component.Xamarin 
--add Component.Xamarin.Inspector 
--add Component.Xamarin.Profiler 
--add Component.Xamarin.RemotedSimulator 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.FSharp 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Merq 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.MonoDebugger 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Static.Analysis.Tools 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DiagnosticTools 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.UWP.Xamarin 
--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.ArchitectureTools.Managed
```

Consult the following links to review options, component ids, etc..

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/create-a-network-installation-of-visual-studio
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed response. I was under the wrong impression that Xamarin was just an add-on tool that could be simply downloaded independently and applied to an existing VS installation, and that it would just add another Project Type/Template when I create a new project. Now I understand it's not that simple.

Comment: @PradeepPuranik Glad I could help. Xamarin is using Visual Studio add-ins (`.vsix`) just like Microsoft is doing, even the C#/VB Rosyln compiler is optional `.vsix`,  but the various `.vsix` are dependent upon a number of "standard" Visual Studio `.vsix`. and the Visual Studio integration framework itself. Thus the Xamarin ones have dependency on the Visual Studio version, 2015/2017, and a number of other `.vsix` add-ins. In the offline layout in my example, you *could* copy the Xamarin based (and their dependencies) to another PC with Visual Studio 2015/2017 installed on it and install them

Comment: That makes sense. Actually I have just developed a Dot Net DLL (in VS 2008) for another dev team to use in their Xamarin project. My initial plan was to install Xamarin in my local machine and to verify if adding my DLL to a Xamarin project would succeed. But seeing how complicated the installation process itself is, and since I don't actively use Xamarin, I guess I'll just hand over my DLL to them and let them test it.

Comment: Hi, if I write `--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat 
--add Component.Xamarin 
--add Component.Xamarin.Inspector 
--add Component.Xamarin.Profiler 
--add Component.Xamarin.RemotedSimulator`

Will I have download less that than the workload alone?
Because `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat` result in over 4GB including the emulator and images for x86 and ARM, soooo many useless stuff required!

Comment: @JonneyShih You have to get the `Required` components of a workload, but not the `Recommended` (--includeRecommended) or `Optional` (--includeOptional) components, then you can add the individual Recommended/Optional components that you want, review the list: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-enterprise (FYI: that link is for a Enterprise license)

Comment: @SushiHangover I know! I downloaded only required components in the workload.  Android Emulator and Images and JDK are required now (15.4) for some reason! Can you answer my question please, what command to download only essential components?

Comment: @JonneyShih ??? In  ...15.4, 15.5, 15.6... The Android components are flagged as `Recommended` in `NetCrossPlat`, not `Required`, if you use `-includeRecommended` you would get them with the workload. In some workloads they are flagged as `Optional`, are you including other workloads as I do not know of any that have a hard `Required` flag on them...

Comment: @SushiHangover I used 15.4.2, they were flagged as required, I used only `--add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NetCrossPlat` and the extra size was over 4.5 GB.

Answer (score 1):

You are targeting Xamarin.iOS,Xamarin.Android or Xamarin.Forms?
As per below system requirement, the minimal Visual Studio version that supported Xamarin is Visual Studio 2013 and it is only for Xamarin.iOS

[Xamarin.iOS](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/):

[image]

[Xamarin.Android](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/):
[image]

[Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/crossplatform/getting_started/requirements/#windows): 
[image]

Comment: Actually I have just developed a Dot Net DLL (in VS 2008) for another dev team to use in their Xamarin project. My initial plan was to install Xamarin in my local machine and to verify if adding my DLL to a Xamarin project would succeed. But seeing how complicated the installation process itself is, and since I don't actively use Xamarin, I guess I'll just hand over my DLL to them and let them test it. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's impossible, [currently supported versions of Visual Studio are 2013+](https://www.xamarin.com/faq#qot-install-in-vs).

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will useful for you.,

File - > New -> Project -> and Click Open Visual Studio Installer. Check this image[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9F3SE.png)