# How to install Xamarin without Android SDKs for Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to install Visual Studio 2017 with Xamarin using its online installer. But when I tick **"Mobile development with .NET"** under **Workloads** it selects an **Android SDK setup** as well. If I try to untick it (Android SDK setup) then Xamarin will also be unticked.

How can I install only Xamarin without any Android SDKs for Visual Studio 2017?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you are freshly installing **Visual Studio 2017**, rather than checking **Mobile development with .NET** under **Workloads** you have to tick **Xamarin** under **Individual Components** in the installer window.
2. If you had already installed Visual Studio 17 **without** Xamarin, then go to,

   *Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features*

   Select **Microsoft Visual Studio 2017** and click on **Change**. In the appeared Window, select **Modify** under your specific Visual Studio version listed.

   Go to the **Individual components** tab, now you can select only **Xamarin** and no other components will be attached to it.

This was my selections under **Individual Components** to install Xamarin without android. The Green Ticks would be a sufficiently enough selection.

[image]

Comment: You can also create an offline installer that only contains Visual Studio & Xamarin without the Android SDK/Emulators : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46464429/4984832